# Generate File Name Dynamically: Based on Content of the File (.bat)

Tags: batch-file, scripting, filenames

I have a requirement where I have to generate the name of the file (and populate it) based on the content.

Here are the details:

Salesforce -> Write a query to extract data in CSV:

[image]

Read file and do the following:

Person A, from New York has requested for Vodka and Person B, from Chicago has requested for Gin, so, create two .csv files with the following naming convention:

Current Year | Month | Day | _Location | _Item Requested

20191230_New York_Vodka.csv: This file would have name, address, phone number of Person A from the main csv

20191230_Chicago_Gin.csv: This file would have name, address, phone number of Person B from the main csv

If 10 people from New York request for Vodka, then all those 10 peoples informations should be listed in 20191230_New York_Vodka.csv from the main csv.

Tomorrow if other people from NY request for Vodka again, then only new people should be included in the file.

I have to write this as a .batch script and I am very inexperienced with scripting. Any help/guidance would be appreciated. TIA  :)

Comment: We cannot help you to fix your code, if you don't post it. In addition to that code, we also need to see a properly formatted example of the content within the `.csv` file, _an image of something loaded into a spreadsheet is of no real use to anybody_. Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60403364/edit) accordingly. It's also worth mentioning that if you have been given a task, for which you have little experience, and you're unsure where to start, then the responsible thing to do is to inform whomever delegated that task, that it is outside of your current skill set.

Comment: Read [ask] and [mcve].